# How to deploy a “Web Deployment Package” to my live server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application deployed inside IIS 7. I did my first deployment by doing the following steps:

- Inside Visual Studio, right click on the Project.
- Publish >> Publish method >> Web Deployment Package
- Then using IIS’s web deployment tool, I deploy the web deployment package to my server successfully.

Now I made many changes to my project inside VS. and I need to do a new deployment to my system. Now I create a new web deployment package from VS, which created a folder that have the following 5 components:

```
.deploy
.deploy-readme
.setParameters
.SourceManifest
.zip
```

Now inside the web deployment .zip file I found the following folders:

```
Model
Content
View
Script
Bin
```

So my question is; if I simply copy the web deployment files inside the .zip folder, including the following folders; Model + Content + View+ Script+ bin, then I paste them inside my server under the following location `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` will it do the required steps to deploy my changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy and paste require files manually. But why do you want to do that when a tool is designed and tested to do just that for you automatically. Considering the fact that there are many files that are required (hidden dependencies, you may desire config file transformation, etc) this manual approach will give you a headache.

Any reason you selected Web Deployment Package?

You can utilize Web Deploy instead. It support one click deployment to any environment with superb config file transformation support. More details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

I am using it in my current project for integration and beta environment successfully since last one year.

Comment: it is not that headache, I will just remove the folders under the C:\inetpub\wwwroot , and copy the new ones from the web deployment package..

Comment: Copy and pasting is not BUT figuring out what to copy may gets difficult later on if not now...

Comment: but what I am not sure about is that I will copy the folders under "Web deployment package>>.zip>>release>>package>>package temp", but the other files under the Web Deployment package such as .deply
.deploy-readme
.setParameters
.SourceManifest will not be copied ?? so is this a problem ?

Comment: May be and may not be. It depends on what's your deployment setup. If these file store e.g. some transformation that the tool perform after copy, manual copy will miss that. You may want to add your last comment in your original post to get better answer. I am speaking generally.

Comment: You should run the cmd file that you got with the package, e.g. `webapplication1.deploy.cmd /y /m:yourServerName /u:windowsAccountOnServer /p:windowsPasswordOnServer`